# How do I grep lines ending on a specific expression

Tags: linux, grep

I have a text file with 4 sentences and I want to grep the ones ending in "me", however when I do grep "me$" it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

(I wanted the result to be the 1st, 2nd and 4th line).

Edit: Replaced image with text.

```
$ cat sm.txt
somebody once told me

somebodyoncetoldme

the world was

gonna roll me
$ grep "me$" sm.txt
$
```

Comment: The extra spacing between the lines in the `cat` output is strange, and the spaces before the prompt string are even stranger. Does `file sm.txt` tell you it is a plain ASCII file or it it reporting DOS-style line ends?

Comment: @rropes, What do you see with `cat -e sm.txt` and/or `od -c sm.txt`

Comment: Also, grep knows how to read files, so you should `grep 'me$' sm.txt`

Comment: @glennjackman I used cat -e sm.txt and this showed up: `somebody once told me^M$
^M$
somebodyoncetoldme^M$
^M$
the world was^M$
^M$
gonna roll me^M$`

Comment: @xenoid it says: _sm.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478851/how-do-i-grep-lines-ending-on-a-specific-expression?noredirect=1#comment876157_478851) you say that `file` identifies the text file as an ASCII text file with CRLF line endings. That's another way of saying it's a DOS text file, possibly generated with an editor on a Windows system.

A DOS text file has, in comparison to a Unix text file, an extra carriage return character at the end of each line, before the newline.  This is why your regular expression does not match, no line actually ends with `me`, they end with `me\r`, where `\r` is a common way of writing a carriage return character.

The remedy for this is to convert your text file to a Unix text file using e.g. the `dos2unix` conversion tool, before using it on a Unix system.

Comment: Alternately, search for lines ending the "me" followed by any whitespace: `grep 'me[[:space:]]*$' file`

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing `grep "me\r$"` but that didn't work, and after that I used the dos2unix conversion tool and did the normal `grep "me$"` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In itself `grep "me$"` definitely is correct. I suspect your lines end with a few additional characters that are hard to see, like tabs and spaces.

Try one of these:

```
# \t means tab
# [\t ] means a tab or a space
# [\t ]* means any number (including zero) of tabs and spaces.
#
grep "me[\t ]*$" sm.txt
```

Or:

```
# [[:space:]] means any white space. I don't know if there are
# more than just space and tabs. This works with GNU grep only.
#
grep "me[[:space:]]*$" sm.txt
```

Comment: `[[:space:]]` _is_ more than just a space or a tab (see `man isspace`). `[[:blank:]]` is only a space or a tab (see `man isblank`).

Comment: I tried both but this: `$ grep "me[\t ]*$" sm.txt
$ grep "me[[:space:]]*$" sm.txt



$` (image since I don't know how to do paragraphs in comments)  https://imgur.com/a/IuQoHSX